# What are minimum number of moves needed to checkmate a king using king and rook?

Tags: endgame, checkmate

Assuming that both players do the best move, I want to know the minimum number of moves needed in the worst case scenario when checkmating a lone king using king and rook.

**Edit**: The worst case does not include "stalemate" or "king able to capture rook" positions, as it will be clearly draw in that cases.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checkmate#King_and_rook

Comment: @DavidRicherby I see, it is written there that it can be forced in 16 moves. You can also post it as answer :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [this site](http://kirill-kryukov.com/chess/longest-checkmates/), the worst case for King + Rook vs. King is the following position, requiring 16 moves to mate (White to move):

```
[FEN "8/8/8/8/8/2k5/1R6/K7 w - - 0 1"]
```

There are other positions which require 16 moves, e.g. with the White King on a1, Rook on e2, and the Black King on d3.

You can play these endgames with an online database viewer, e.g. [Shredder](http://www.shredderchess.com/online-chess/online-databases/endgame-database.html).

The worst case scenario (for White) with Black to move is when Black is stalemated or can capture the rook, when it is a draw. With White to move, all positions are won.

Comment: So that means we can deliver checkmate under 16 moves from any position?

Comment: @berserk yes, that's correct.

Comment: except for positions where the rook is immediately captured of course.

Comment: @user1583209 And positions where the lone king is stalemated (e.g., switch the positions of the two kings in the diagram in this answer).

Comment: I'm confused. Is the image depicting the "starting" positions for the 3 pieces, or the "ending" (checkmate) positions? If this is the "checkmate" position, then shouldn't the Rook be Black instead of White (or exchange the two Kings)?

Comment: @KevinFegan This is the starting position; from this position it takes 16 moves to mate Black, and there is no position with K+R vs. K where mate is acheivable but it takes longer than 16 moves.  (If the rook were Black it wouldn't be checkmate, because White isn't in check in such a position; instead it's stalemate, as the comment above you notes.)

Comment: @user1583209 yes, except stalemate positions and rook capture positions. I will add this in my question.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Is there any possible scenario where it takes more than 16 moves to checkmate?

Comment: @berserk There is not (at least not for R+K vs. K) - that's the point of this answer; this is the 'worst-case scenario'.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki oh ok. I got confused with what you said before "but it takes longer than 16 moves".

Comment: @berserk Steven wrote "_there is no position_ with K+R vs. K where mate is achievable but it takes longer than 16 moves" (emphasis mine).

Comment: Is the position in the diagram the only position (apart from equivalent positions in the other 3 corners of the board) where it takes 16 moves?

Comment: @user1583209 no, there are more positions. I updated my answer.